# Solr Cassandra integration

Tags: indexing, solr, cassandra, lucene

I am trying to integrate solr with cassandra.
What I have tried 
**https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index**
I have successfully compiled and run , I have tried ant build with external cassandra too but failed.

**https://github.com/tjake/Solandra**

but this one is only supported with cassandra 1.X

Can some one please suggest me how I can do this? Also what will be good indexing data in cassandra or extracing to solr and then index data in solr.
Thanks

Comment: "tried ant build with external cassandra too but failed."....  I can clearly see this is maven build from the build and install section. why are you trying maven build? if you dont have maven installed,... install and try.  maven build  should work.

Comment: actually last commit on 'Solandra' is 2012 so i wonder if it support cassandra 3.x , as i have successfully build it with built in cassandra 1.2.x which has cli , but i need it built with cassandra 3.x .
Thanks

Comment: I was talking about first link not solandra